# Многоуровневая иерархия java

Tags: java

Вопрос таков, почему при вызове конструктора С вызывается еще и конструкторы А и В. Тоесть в классах наследниках будут вызываться все конструкторы объявленные в суперклассах?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, так задумано изначально. Любой конструктор в самом начале своей работы вызывает конструктор своего родителя ( а тот может своего).

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что прежде, чем вы сможете иметь дело с членами данных базовых классов в теле конструктора производного класса, или при инициализации его собственных членов, эти члены данных базовых классов должны быть созданы. Любой производный объект включает в себя все члены данных своих базовых классов.

Answer (score 0):

Разбирался с вопросом и набрел на важную вещь, которой хотел бы поделиться. 
Если цепочка наследования - больше 2 звеньев, например супер-класс -> суб-класс -> суб-суб-класс, то конструкторы родительских классов вызываются начиная с самого первого супер-класса. Чтобы быть еще точным, сначала вызывается конструктор класса Object, от которого наследуются все супер-классы.

Comment: У вас возник новый вопрос? Или что значит ваше сообщение?