# Вызов конструктора класса родителя в Java. В чём важность?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток всем. Читая книгу Брюса Эккеля, натолкнулся на следующий текст:

> Конечно, очень важно, чтобы подобъект базового класса был правильно
>   инициализирован, и гарантировать это можно только одним способом:
>   выполнить инициализацию в конструкторе, вызывая при этом конструктор
>   базового класса, у которого есть необходимые знания и привилегии для
>   проведения инициализации базового класса. Java автоматически вставляет
>   вызовы конструктора базового класса в конструктор производного класса.

Помогите разобраться, почему же так важно вызвать конструктор базового класса для класса наследника? И что будет если это не произойдёт (теоретически)? Спасибо.

Comment: Предполагается, что наследник использует функционал базового класса, который не может работать, если требуемая для него инициализция не была произведена.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Базовый класс по сути является как-бы частью наследника. Поэтому, если он не будет проинициализирован, то работать ничего не будет.

Пример:

```
public class A {
    protected int valA = 1;
}

public class B extends A {
    protected int valB = 2;
    public int getVal(){
        return valB + valA;   
    }
}
```

Наследование позволяет писать такую конструкцию. Если родительский класс не будет инициализировн, то в строке `return valB + valA;` будет неизвестно значение `valA`.

Насколько я понимаю, не может быть ситуации, когда конструктор базового класса не вызовется (поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь). [Пример автоматического вызова конструкторов базовых классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463553/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F-java).

Answer (score 9):

Это действительно важно. И вот почему. У базового класса может быть (и весьма часто бывает) какое-то внутренне состояние, которое нужно правильно инициализировать. И если этого не сделать, то ваш класс скорее всего не сможет правильно работать. 
Простой пример (код может содержать синтаксические ошибки - пишу без компилятора. Но суть, думаю, будет понятна):

```
class Base {
    public Base(int size) {
        _someData = new int[size];
    }

    protected int[] _someData;
}

class Child extends Base {
    public Child(int size) {
        // super(size);
    }

    void doSomething(int index, int value) {
        /// ...
        _someData[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Допустим, вы в конструкторе Child не вызвали конструктор предка Base. И тогда при вызове метода doSomething вы получите исключение, так как поле _someData не было инициализировано, так как его инициализация происходит в конструкторе предка, который вы не вызывали.

Таких примеров, в том числе и куда более сложных, может быть очень много. К тому же ситуация может усугубляться, если вы создаете класс-наследник от класса, исходников которого у вас нет. Тогда вы вообще не можете знать, какие проблемы могут случиться с "недоинициализированным" классом до тех пор, пока с этими проблемами не столкнетесь

Answer (score 2):

В общем то в цитате из Эккеля и так все достаточно подробно написано.
Класс-наследник только расширяет (дополняет) или изменяет функционал класса-родителя и не является самостоятельным классом, соответственно для работы класса-наследника необходимы инициализицации, производимые в базовом классе.
Если этого не сделать, то вы получите различного вида экзепшены, указывающие на то, что именно не проинициализировано.

Так же, если базовый класс не производит никакой инициализации и прочих действий, на которые опирается класс-наследник, то вызов его в конструкторе не требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Практически, если вы попытаетесь каким-то образом исключить вызов конструктора родительского класса, то компилятор сообщит об ошибке.

Теоретически это означает, что у вас не будет корректно создан объект дочернего класса, потому что та часть объекта или некоторая функциональность, которая относится к родительскому подобъекту, не будет инициализирована или выполнена, и  поведение программы будет неопределенным.

Например, родительский объект может иметь `private` данные, которые кроме него самого никто инициализировать не может. Или родительский объект при своем конструировании может выделять и запрашивать какие-нибудь ресурсы, как, например, открытие файла или базы данных, установление соединения в сети, установка различных системных флагов и т.д.